# Event 4098, 0x80070533 Logon failure: account currently disabled?

Tags: windows-7, group-policy, microsoft-office-2007, eventviewer

Having started to upgrade our PCs to Windows 7 we have noticed that we are getting group policy warnings in Event Viewer such as:

"The user 'Word.qat' preference item in the 'a_Office2007_Users {A084A37B-6D4C-41C0-8AF7-B891B87FC53B}' Group Policy object did not apply because it failed with error code '0x80070533 Logon failure: account currently disabled.' This error was suppressed."

15 of these warnings appear every two hours on every Windows 7 PC, most of which are to do with core office applications and two are for plug-ins to out document management system.

These warnings aren't afecting the users, but it would be nice to track down the source of them before we rollout Win7 to the rest of the Organisation.

Any ideas as to where the login issue could be comming from (All users are connecting to the domain and proxy, etc fine)?

Comment: r u using gpo's to deploy your office applications?  Also how are you doing the upgrades osd/wds/manual etc.?

Comment: 1. No.
2. We are using WDS, wiping the PC and installing our Win7 build, which includes office and our other basic software.

Answer (score 3):

The error should be harmless.  It isn't applying a GPO-defined MS office 2007 setting, because the account it is trying to apply it to is disabled (so it won't matter anyway).

If you want to get rid of it, locate the GPO item referenced in the error message, and move it to a GPO that won't be applied to disabled users.  This would likely require having the disabled users in a separate OU from enabled ones.

You could also remove the local profiles of disabled users from all your workstations.

Fixing this is almost certainly more trouble than it is worth.  By definition, nobody will ever notice this issue besides seeing it in the logs.

It happens every 2 hours because that is the GPO update interval.

Answer (score 1):

Every 2 hours on every Windows 7 PC? H-m-m...

Have you got any Windows Server 2008 domain controller in your environment? Group policy extensions comes with Windows 2008 server allow to configure additional Gruop policy features including Scheduled tasks. Old clients (like XP or Windows 2003 server) does not support it and not affected.

So seems you have (may be by default) a group policy object for assgning custom (preconfigured) Office 2007 Quick Access Toolbar (.qat) for your users. Please check it with Group Policy Management tool.